# In angular, how to instantiate a class that has injected service at its constructor

Tags: angular

How to create a TypeScript class in angular with a service injected and instantiate that class? Let say you have a class Employee that has one parameter on its contructor 'IEmployeeInfo' to initialize the object and also an injected angular service 'SomeService'. Then how to instantiate that class?

```
export class Employee {
  constructor(employeeInfo: IEmployeeInfo, _someService: SomeService) {}
   //using the method from injected service
    this._someService.doSomething(employeeInfo);

   //methods
    soSomeStuff(){...}
    otherMethods(){..}
}



@Component({..})
export class employeeTransaction {
     // how to instantiate a new Employee object?
     const emp1 = new Employee(employeeArgs, service???);
     emp1.doSomeStuff();
     emp1.otherMethods();
}
```

Comment: You inject the service in your component, and pass it as argument to the constructor. What's the difficulty?

Comment: thanks, I just realized that was a dumb question, cheers!